# How to reset stack from a 'More' page in react navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a bottomTabNavigator which has 5 screens, all linking to their own stack. The 5th stack is a 'more' stack. When I am within a page in the 'more' stack I want to be able to click back to one of the other tabs and the stack be cleared so that when I return to 'more' it starts from the top of its stack, not the last page that was visited.

I have tried several solutions found on Stack Overflow and none have worked. A couple appear to be from a deprecated version of react navigation.

Is there a way I can do this?

I have tried this...

```
const MainTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: HomeStack,
      },

    ... other screens ...

    More: {
        screen: MoreStack,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarOnPress: ({navigation}) => {

             if  (!navigation.isFocused) {
               navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
             }

            }
        },
      }
```

...but it does not work for me. My resetAction is as so...

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'MainTabNavigator' })],
})
```

I have tried other methods of resetting the action from answers on Stack Overflow but none of them have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `popToTop()` in `tabBarOnPress`.

However, this only works properly if applied to every tab, so if there's a tab in which you'd rather keep the last visited screen, then this solution won't work.

```js
YourRouteName: {
  screen: YourStack,
  navigationOptions: {
    tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation }) => {
      navigation.navigate({
        routeName: navigation.state.routeName,
        action: navigation.popToTop()
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That actually worked exactly the way I wanted it to, thanks!  However, one side question... with this fix, when on a page within the more stack I then click a bottom tab, but when I go back to the 'More" tab it shows the previous page sliding out instead of automatically showing the main 'More' page in the stack. It does show the default 'more' page as I want it to, but it shows the page I was previously on in the 'More' stack sliding out first.

Comment: Not sure, here's a snack I've made that shows this in action, which doesn't show the page sliding out: https://snack.expo.io/BJNuGBRsE

Comment: Hmm, you're right, it doesn't do that in your snack. I will try to compare what I got to what you got and figure it out. Thanks for your help.